# Basic obfuscation program

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k=0;
    string s;

    cout<<"string "; 

    getline(cin,s);             //taking in a string from the user

    float n=s.size();          //storing size of string

    int f=floor((sqrt(n)));   //floor of square root of input string

    int c=ceil((sqrt(n)));    //ceiling 

    int m=f*c;               //storing product of f and c

     vector< vector<string> > vec(n<=m?f:++f, vector<string>(c)); //makes a 2d vector 
                                                                  //depending on user's 
                                                                  //string length


    for(int i=0;n<=m?i<f:i<++f;i++)        //looping acc to user's input and assigning   
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)           //string to a matrix   
        {
            if(k<s.size())
            {
                vec[i][j]=s[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }



    for(int j=0;j<c;j++)        //printing the vector
        {

    {
        for(int i=0;n<=m?i<f:i<++f;i++)

            cout<<vec[i][j];

    }cout<<" ";
        }

getch();         

}
```

It's not working for n>m as for a string of length 8 characters it makes a vector of 2*3 thus failing to enclose the whole string in the matrix and which is why I am using ternary so as to make a vector of bigger size when it encounters cases like these.
.So what am I doing wrong?

I'll just write the whole question.

```
One classic method for composing secret messages is called a square code.  The spaces are removed from the english text and the characters are written into a square (or rectangle). The width and height of the rectangle have the constraint,

    floor(sqrt(word)) <= width, height <= ceil(sqrt(word))

    The coded message is obtained by reading down the columns going left to right. For example, the message above is coded as:

    imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau


    Sample Input:

    chillout

    Sample Output:

    clu hlt io
```

Comment: Could you a) format the code nicely and b) explain the principle idea of the algorithm. It's time consuming to guess that out of the code (that even doesn't work correctly, yet)

Comment: This code is unreadablePh'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn

Comment: Big +1 for the Cthulu reference. ;)

Comment: Haha I am being ripped apart here.But please bear with me as I am new to programming as well as this site.I have edited my post and I hope the code is more readable now.

Comment: You should have been immediately able to see that this: `vector< vector<string> > vec(n<=m?f:++f, vector<string>(c));` is just wrong, without having to even read it. Use of the comma operator in a ternary expression, one clause of the expression having type `int`, the other having type `std::vector<string>` - it's just obviously and intuitively wrong. Write something simpler, more obvious, and more expressive of what you're trying to achieve, particularly if you're "new to programming".

Comment: @PaulGriffiths The ternary is just there to assign the size to the vector and I can't understand why it would have any bearing on the vector.

Comment: @Ratul: Exactly my point. If you don't understand your own solution, and why it isn't working, then you should choose a simpler one that you can understand. A construct like that will almost inevitably contain errors.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I don't think the comma is *technically* being used in the ternary (otherwise this may not compile), but it is easy to get confused there.  I do agree that it shouldn't be crammed into an argument like that.

Comment: @Jamal Yeah it compiles alright.It was working yesterday for values 6,7,and 8,so today I tried making a generalized solution but it's not working.The comma is used to give the column value to the vector.I know it's chaotic, so I can do with some sophisticated(working ) alternatives.

Comment: @Ratul: My review back at CR may shed some light on this.  I too had to carefully examine that line, so my solution may still be misleading.

Comment: @Jamal: You may be right, but as you say, just goes to prove the point.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: my answer can be found [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32530/22222). Essentially, I set a new variable `size` to the value taken from the ternary, then used `size` as an argument in the vector in place of the ternary.

Comment: @Jamal: Good answer, I like all the points.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Thanks.  I was a little unsure about the casting, but I went the safe route with mentioning it.  One answer I've found here stated that too much casting indicates bad design.

Answer (score 2):

This won't fix your entire problem, but I still feel it is important.  You seem to misunderstand how the ternary works.  Let's observe one of its uses here:

```
for (int i = 0; n <= m ? i < f : i < ++f; i++) {}
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <--- not the intended outcome
```

This will not work because the returned side of the ternary does *not* "stick" itself in-place.  In other words, neither `i < f` nor `i < ++f` will be put directly into the for-loop.  Instead, it'll give you a *value*.

To see what it's really doing, you'll first need to understand that the ternary is just another way to do an if-else.  The ternary above, put into if-else form, looks like this:

```
if (n <= m)
    i < f;   // left side of the ":"
else
    i < ++f; // right side of the ":"
```

Let's break it down further:

```
i < f
```

This is doing a *less-than comparison* of `i` and `f`.  So, depending on the individual values, you'll receive either a 0 (false) or a 1 (true).

So, in your for-loop, this will occur:

```
for (int i = 0; 1; i++) {}
//              ^  <--- if comparison returns true

for (int i = 0; 0; i++) {}
//              ^  <--- if comparison returns false
```

So, for your example, you'll need to find the value of `f` *before* the loop.  You *can* use a ternary for that part, but only if you understand it.  Otherwise, use another method to find `f` (the intended numerical value).  Once you find it, *then* you can put `i < f` into the for-loop.

Comment: How do you grey out code in comments?My above comment is pretty difficult to comprehend `right now`.

Comment: @Ratul: Put a backtick (`) between the text.

Comment: I have stored the value in `f` before the loop I think.For example let the length of string be 8.So f will store `(floor(sqrt(8)))` ie `2` and `c=3` and `m=2*3` ie `6`.So now to assigning the size to the vector.The ternary inside the vector will check if `(8<=6)` `(row=2)` `else(row=++f ie 3)` and then the for loop will work according to the vector created ie either `i<2`(if true) or `i<3`(if false)

Comment: This is already there in the code that I posted here.So in a way no would be the answer.

Comment: @Ratul: Okay.  I was able to reproduce your issue, but I still can't quite find the solution.  Just keep looking over the code to determine why the loop is going out of range.